# how to pass multiple arguments into curried function on an event

Tags: reactjs

How to pass multiple arguments into a curried function on an event?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.sumFunction = this.sumFunction.bind(this);
  }


  sumFunction = a => e => b {
    let score = e.target.value
  }

  render() {
     return (
       <div>
        <div value="100" onClick={(e) =>this.sumFunction(1, e, 2)}>click on this</div>
       </div>
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: The curried function declaration... Is that by mistake or intended? Sumfunction = (a,b,c) => ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can call the functions successively, like so:

```
  render() {
     return (
       <div>
        <div value="100" onClick={(e) => this.sumFunction(1)(e)(2)}>click on this</div>
       </div>
     )
  }
```

Also, note that there's a missing `=>` in the `sumFunction` declaration:

```
  // adding a '=>' to the right of b
  sumFunction = a => e => b => {
    let score = e.target.value
  }
```